# Why the execution time of same function definition within a class is slower more than 10x time?

Tags: c++, performance, function, optimization, compiler-optimization

Not sure which kind of optimization the `compiler` does, but why within a class a same function definition is slower than the same called as global method?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#define MAX_BUFFER 256
const int whileLoops = 1024 * 1024 * 10;

void TracedFunction(int blockSize) {
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point pStart;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point pEnd;

    double A[MAX_BUFFER];
    double B[MAX_BUFFER];
    double C[MAX_BUFFER];

    // fill A/B
    for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < MAX_BUFFER; sampleIndex++) {
        A[sampleIndex] = sampleIndex;
        B[sampleIndex] = sampleIndex + 1000.0;
    }

    // same traced function
    pStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    int whileCounter = 0;
    while (whileCounter < whileLoops) {
        for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < blockSize; sampleIndex++) {
            double value = A[sampleIndex] + B[sampleIndex];

            C[sampleIndex] = value;
        }

        whileCounter++;
    }

    pEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "execution time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(pEnd - pStart).count() << " ms" << " | fake result: " << A[19] << " " << B[90] << " " << C[129] << std::endl;
}

class OptimizeProcess
{
public:
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point pStart;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point pEnd;

    double A[MAX_BUFFER];
    double B[MAX_BUFFER];
    double C[MAX_BUFFER];

    OptimizeProcess() {
        // fill A/B
        for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < MAX_BUFFER; sampleIndex++) {
            A[sampleIndex] = sampleIndex;
            B[sampleIndex] = sampleIndex + 1000.0;
        }
    }

    void TracedFunction(int blockSize) {
        // same traced function
        pStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        int whileCounter = 0;
        while (whileCounter < whileLoops) {
            for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < blockSize; sampleIndex++) {
                double value = A[sampleIndex] + B[sampleIndex];

                C[sampleIndex] = value;
            }

            whileCounter++;
        }

        pEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "execution time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(pEnd - pStart).count() << " ms" << " | fake result: " << A[19] << " " << B[90] << " " << C[129] << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    int blockSize = MAX_BUFFER;

    // outside class
    TracedFunction(blockSize);

    // within class
    OptimizeProcess p1;
    p1.TracedFunction(blockSize);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Tried with `MSVC`, `/Oi /Ot`.

~80ms vs 1200ms. Is there loop unrolling using `blockSize` as constant at `compile-time`?

Not sure, since I've tried to set `blockSize` random with:

```
std::mt19937_64 gen{ std::random_device()() };
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dis{ 0.0, 1.0 };

int blockSize = dis(gen) * 255 + 1;
```

Same results...

Comment: Did you compile with optimization on ?  Because here, I get alsmost the same figure for both exectuions: https://ideone.com/uZK787

Comment: @Christophe: yes, as I said `/Oi /Ot`

Comment: And [/O2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f8h5cxt.aspx), still the same ?

Comment: I see there are differences in memory allocation. In global function, you are doing it within the function body, in class arrays are pre-allocated in advance. Fall to different places, depending on your machine / load, access time might be different. Comparing them is like comparing apples with grapes.

Comment: The output in my computer is: `execution time: 9647 ms | fake result: 19 1090 1258
execution time: 9565 ms | fake result: 19 1090 1258`. I am using gcc compiler, Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I get similar timings in VC++2017 with full optimization: `execution time: 68 ms | fake result: 2.22523e-306 2.20691e-312 1.13591e-305
execution time: 1008 ms | fake result: 2.22523e-306 4.51917e-309 1.13592e-305`

Comment: A `system()` call, really? why? BTW, I see only 1.4 speedup, but still.. With `O2`.

Comment: @muratm that's not true, arrays are allocated on the stack in both cases (as local variables in one case, as members of a local variable in the other case).

Comment: With zero-initialized arrays: 74 ms vs. 1024 ms. I bet the compiler optimizes most of the loops away, as the observable effect does not depend on the whole result.

Comment: @Mat that is likely to be the reason. In the case of everything in one function the compiler can see that the arrays aren't initialized and remove everything to do with them. In the case of the member function it can't, because it can't see whether the arrays were initialized somewhere else before the member function is called.

Comment: @Pezo, yeah, right missed / assumed `OptimizeProcess p1`.

Comment: @Pezo: if I init both arrays in both function, nothing change (still 80 vs 1200 ms ~).

Comment: That's strange, I'm on mobile just now so I can't test, sorry.

Comment: Compiling the same [slightly modified code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7chhvU) (removing iostream/chrono and making the arrays global in order for the compiler not to optimise them away) on Godbolt shows that the same code is generated for both versions. Thus, any further discussion is pointless.

Comment: Oh BTW, have you looked at the generated assembly? Maybe post a godbolt link.

Comment: @muradm: I think it should be like Pezo, but if I do as you suggest (i.e. move the array/init in the main and pass them as pointer, both goes around ~80ms) :O Very strange

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: how do you "init" the arrays? In the main so? Can you show the whole example? Not sure why if I init within a function it should remove it :O

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: looks my updated answer with array inits: in fact it don't take them away (since std::cout print correct values). So still not sure what's happening...

Comment: Here you can see that gcc almost generates the same code (except some minor differences due to inlining.  But you see that MSVC seems to reload the this base at every iteration:  https://godbolt.org/z/66c5rJ

Comment: @markzzz : There's too much noise in your original code to precisely say what's going on. The only thing I can advise is to initialise the arrays outside of your calculation function and pass already initialised arrays/pointers/objects into it : this way, [the disassembly is much clearer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1u9kVF), the function is responsible for one thing only, and does not care how the arrays are initialised.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar do you mean somethings lke this? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0063855e4fdef0c8 in MSVC here returns ~80ms on both, but I feel it throw array away (so no calculating it, since its too slow the exection time). But the strange things is that std::cout print "correct" result, so can't delete them :O

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar you completely changed the semantics of the code, so there's bound to be differences. It's just not useful any more for reasoning about the original example.

Comment: Your modified sample code still isn't a valid benchmark. The outer loop `while (whileCounter < whileLoops)` doesn't affect the result at all. Also you should make sure that the whole result affects the output (i. e. output all elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile with the maximum optimization flag of GCC, i.e. `O3`, then you will get similar execution times.

*There is no difference in the aspect of executing a function within or not a class, w.r.t. execution time.*

---

The only difference that I see, is when and how you create your arrays. In the first function, the arrays are automatic variables of the function. In the within function, the arrays are data members of the class.

That can play a role in certain cases. Make the arrays global (create them only once), and you will see no difference in your execution times (regardless of using `O1`, `O2` or `O3`).

---

Note: Compile with `O2`, and you will get a faster execution time for the within function (that's the other way around of what you mention). To be precise a x1.35 speedup, as you can see in the <kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kjscQGOLaxDVWSmr)</kbd>.

Nevertheless, remember than when optimization is done right, with `O3` in this case, you shouldn't see any significant differences whatsoever!

Comment: This can be memory address calculation difference. One is calculated in relation to the offset of the object location on the stack, which can be a bit more complex, than in case of simple function. Also there is that suspicious for me `double value` variable in your loop within the class, @markzzz. It might affect the use of registers, or in worst case additional allocations.

Comment: @muradm that variable is there in both cases, it should most certainly be optimized away in both cases too.

Comment: @Pezo, ah I see, new loops added. mismatched them, sorry for `double value`, taking that thing back, but not the other.